# Android: source code Google Keep app

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Действую по схеме c [`SO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Apk Extractor'ом вытащил апк кипа
Через апк тул пытаюсь вытащить манифест файла, но всё крешется.

В чем может быть проблема? Может у кого есть уже сорцы гуглкипа (гуглил, весь гитхаб прошерстил, не нашел...)?

Comment: http://www.decompileandroid.com/ может это поможет? А вообще разве keep опен сорс?

Comment: @Deadkenny - Спасибо, хороший сервис, но не помог, манифест пустой и файлы имеют странные названия...

Нет, кип не опен сорс, но к примеру я находил исходники часов из `Kitkat` ([`alarm-clock`][3]) пускай и немного модифицированные.

![alt text][1] 

![alt text][2]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/2p2aF3V.png
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/m7n6rcx.png
  [3]: https://github.com/klinker41/alarm-clock

Comment: успешно декомпелировал с помощью этого приложения https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava&hl=ru